# Ansible can't find python even if ansible_python_interpreter is specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible

I've installed python 3.8.5 with Homebrew which [places a symlink](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python) to the executable at `/usr/local/bin/python3` which points to the actual executable at `/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3`

I can enter either of those into my shell to open the python3 repl:

```sh
$ /usr/local/bin/python3 
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 21 2020, 10:42:08) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^D

$ /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 21 2020, 10:42:08) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I have an inventory with the following host that specifies the path to the symlink:

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    vm:
      ansible_ssh_host: 127.0.0.1
      ansible_ssh_port: 2222
      ansible_user: "{{ deploy_username }}"
      host_key_checking: false
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3
```

When I try to ping my server, I get this error:

```
$ ansible all -i inventory.yml -m ping
vm | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/python3: No such file or directory\r\n",
    "msg": "The module failed to execute correctly, you probably need to set the interpreter.\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 127
}
```

The error says it can't find python3. I get the same error if I try to use the longer path through the framework. If I remove the `ansible_python_interpreter` line from my inventory, it will default back to the system python `/usr/bin/python` but that has no libraries installed so I can't use it (and would prefer not to as it's an older version and managed by the system not me).

Why can't Ansible find my python version even when I specify the full path?

Comment: I had faced a similar issue with an older version of ansible & python. `$ python=<python-interpreter-path> ansible ...` worked for me then.

Comment: Post "ansible all -i inventory.yml -m ping -vvv". Find out how and what host you connect. Try "ssh -p 2222 deploy_username@127.0.01" and see whether you can find Python or not.

Comment: To isolate the problem try Python without symlink.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration below works with Python3 (3.6, 3.7, 3.8)

```sh
shell> ssh -p 22 admin@127.0.0.1 which python3.6
/usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

```yaml
shell> cat .ansible/hosts
all:
  hosts:
    vm:
      ansible_ssh_host: 127.0.0.1
      ansible_ssh_port: 22
      ansible_user: admin
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

```
shell> ansible all -m ping -vvv
ansible 2.8.5
  config file = /home/acadmin/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/acadmin/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/local/share/py36-ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.9 (default, Nov 14 2019, 01:16:50) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 6.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_601/final 335540)]
Using /home/acadmin/.ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /home/acadmin/.ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
script declined parsing /home/acadmin/.ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /home/acadmin/.ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
Parsed /home/acadmin/.ansible/hosts inventory source with yaml plugin
META: ran handlers
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/ping.py
Pipelining is enabled.
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
<127.0.0.1> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o Port=22 -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="admin"' -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o ControlPath=/usr/home/acadmin/.ansible/cp/bfe1967dc6 127.0.0.1 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/local/bin/python3.6 && sleep 0'"'"''
<127.0.0.1> (0, b'\n{"ping": "pong", "invocation": {"module_args": {"data": "pong"}}}\n', b'')
vm | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "data": "pong"
        }
    },
    "ping": "pong"
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers
```

Comment: Hmmm, this looks like your connecting to a local server and then checking it's python location. For some reason I was under the impression that I didn't need any particular version of python on the remote server that I was configuring. Maybe that is false/naive?

Comment: This answer provides you with an example of how to update your question.